# Programmatically moving to next panorama item on a listbox tap

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to move to the next panorama item page when a Listbox item is clicked?

I have tried this below but its giving me a read only error

**EDIT: I have figured out how to achieve this but it is setting my background image the same as it would appear in the first item, does anyone know of a way around this?**

```
private void myListBox_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
 {
      pano.SelectedItem = 1;
 }
```

PanoramaPage1.xaml

```
<!--LayoutRoot contains the root grid where all other page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <controls:Panorama Name="pano" Title="Trending Now" ItemsSource="{Binding}" FontSize="12">

        <!--Assigns a background image to the Panorama control.-->
        <controls:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/TrendApp;component/Images/pan.png" />
        </controls:Panorama.Background>
        <controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="100" Margin="0,50,0,0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
        <controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="40" Margin="0,50,0,0" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate >

        <!--Panorama item one-->

        <controls:PanoramaItem Name="p1" Header="Trends">
            <Grid>

                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Trend}"  Foreground="White" Height="494" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,12,-13,0" Name="myListbox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431"  TabIndex="10" Tap="myListBox_Tap">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="26" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tblTrend" Text="{Binding TrendItemTag}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="26"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="tblTrend2" Text=">" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                                <Line X1="0" X2="500" Y1="0" Y2="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="White" Opacity="1" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" Margin="0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

            </Grid>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Name="item2" Header="" FontSize="10">

            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
        <!--Panorama item three.-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Search">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" Text="Search" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" />
            </Grid>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the SelectedIndex and SelectedItem are readonly. The only workaround that I know of is setting the DefaultItem like this:

pano.DefaultItem = myPanoramaItem;

[See also this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/fcd5c779-ff57-4426-9d12-29697d0b1d06)

This is all pretty ugly because it doesn't do the animation. On the other hand: I don't think the control was ever meant to be used this way. I only use this way of setting the current item when returning to the page thought the back-button or getting coming from sleep.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, 'pano' is the name of my control in my xaml is this correct? ` <controls:Panorama Name="pano" >`

Comment: Is your myPanoramaItem an int?

Comment: no this doesn't work. I mixed up the Panorama and the Pivot control. My edit is correct.

Comment: As pointed out in the link above 'The background image will start at the new DefaultItem.'  how do I set it to be the middle part of the background image?

Comment: I don't know. You could experiment with giving the background a margin but that will require some calculation to get it right depending on the size of the image. Again: don't think the control was meant to be manipulated through code; the only valid reason to do this seems to me when returning (back-button) or returning from 'sleep'.

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/96612/576859.aspx)

I needed `MyPanorama.DefaultItem = MyPanorama.Items[1];`